# Split a list of file paths in python

Tags: python

I have a list of file path strings. I want to end up with a list of split file path strings.

before:

```
path_list = ['path/to/file.txt', 'path/to/another/file.txt', 'another/path/to/afile.txt', 'justafile.txt']
```

desired output:

```
[['path/', 'to/', 'file.txt'], 
 ['path/', 'to/', 'another/', 'file.txt'], 
 ['another/', 'path/', 'to/', 'afile.txt'], 
 ['justafile.txt']]
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
path_list = ['path/to/file.txt', 'path/to/another/file.txt', 'another/path/to/afile.txt', 'justafile.txt']
new_list = []
for i in path_list:
    new_list.append(Path(i).parts)
```

It is close, but loses the slashes (/).

Comment: Why do you need the slashes? You can simply add them back when you join the list elements

Comment: You can also use `Path(*parts)` to create a Path from the list of parts. It will add the slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you don't need the slashes in your path parts. And if you really do, then you could simply append `os.path.sep` to each part.

With that said, you can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a fixed backward looking pattern that retains the separator:

```
import re
import os
split_paths = [re.split(f'(?<={os.path.sep})', p) for p in path_list]
```

```
print (split_paths)
# [['path/', 'to/', 'file.txt'], ['path/', 'to/', 'another/', 'file.txt'], ['another/', 'path/', 'to/', 'afile.txt'], ['justafile.txt']]
```

[More information on regex lookarounds](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: since my answer adds nothing to this one except for the link to read more about lookaround regex assertions, I'll delete it and put here the link: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @WalterTross thank you for that, added the link to the answer for posterity :]

Answer (score 0):

With [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) matching:

```
import re

path_list = ['path/to/file.txt', 'path/to/another/file.txt', 'another/path/to/afile.txt', 'justafile.txt']
paths = [re.findall(r'([^/]+/?)', p) for p in path_list]
print(paths)
```

---

```
[['path/', 'to/', 'file.txt'], ['path/', 'to/', 'another/', 'file.txt'], ['another/', 'path/', 'to/', 'afile.txt'], ['justafile.txt']]
```